# lookup count on different tab using 2 variables

Tags: count, sum, vlookup, countif

I have data on one excel sheet where there are about 10 columns But I need to count data using just two of them. For Example:

Column C has district names and Column D says what their title is.

The file has hundreds of entries and I need to know how many Admins are in district 1. Only that the results would be on a different tab. I have tried using Vlookup but my knowledge only takes me as far as looking up just one criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If your "one excel sheet" is called Sheet1, `district 1` is in ColumnC of that sheet and `Admins` in ColumnD of that sheet then on a different tab:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!C:C,"district 1",Sheet1!D:D,"Admins")
```